# How to add dynamically stockEvents (markers) in amCharts?

Tags: javascript, events, real-time, amcharts

I'm trying to plot events (markers) in real time, using amCharts.

I've found an example in codepen which shows how to insert those events, but they are static.

```
//https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boWJMQ
var chartData = [];
generateChartData();

function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date( 2012, 0, 1 );
  firstDate.setDate( firstDate.getDate() - 500 );
  firstDate.setHours( 0, 0, 0, 0 );

  for ( var i = 0; i < 500; i++ ) {
    var newDate = new Date( firstDate );
    newDate.setDate( newDate.getDate() + i );

    var a = Math.round( Math.random() * ( 40 + i ) ) + 100 + i;
    var b = Math.round( Math.random() * 100000000 );

    chartData.push( {
      "date": newDate,
      "value": a,
      "volume": b
    } );
  }
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataSets": [ {
    "color": "#b0de09",
    "fieldMappings": [ {
      "fromField": "value",
      "toField": "value"
    }, {
      "fromField": "volume",
      "toField": "volume"
    } ],
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "categoryField": "date",
    // EVENTS
    "stockEvents": [ {
      "date": new Date( 2010, 8, 19 ),
      "type": "sign",
      "backgroundColor": "#85CDE6",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "S",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2010, 10, 19 ),
      "type": "flag",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "backgroundAlpha": 0.5,
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "F",
      "description": "Some longer\ntext can also\n be added"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2010, 11, 10 ),
      "showOnAxis": true,
      "backgroundColor": "#85CDE6",
      "type": "pin",
      "text": "X",
      "graph": "g1",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2010, 11, 26 ),
      "showOnAxis": true,
      "backgroundColor": "#85CDE6",
      "type": "pin",
      "text": "Z",
      "graph": "g1",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 0, 3 ),
      "type": "sign",
      "backgroundColor": "#85CDE6",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "U",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 1, 6 ),
      "type": "sign",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "D",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 3, 5 ),
      "type": "sign",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "L",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 3, 5 ),
      "type": "sign",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "R",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 5, 15 ),
      "type": "arrowUp",
      "backgroundColor": "#00CC00",
      "graph": "g1",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 6, 25 ),
      "type": "arrowDown",
      "backgroundColor": "#CC0000",
      "graph": "g1",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 8, 1 ),
      "type": "text",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "Longer text can\nalso be displayed",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    } ]
  } ],


  "panels": [ {
    "title": "Value",
    "stockGraphs": [ {
      "id": "g1",
      "valueField": "value"
    } ],
    "stockLegend": {
      "valueTextRegular": " ",
      "markerType": "none"
    }
  } ],

  "chartScrollbarSettings": {
    "graph": "g1"
  },

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
    "graphBulletSize": 1,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.5
  },

  "periodSelector": {
    "periods": [ {
      "period": "DD",
      "count": 10,
      "label": "10 days"
    }, {
      "period": "MM",
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 month"
    }, {
      "period": "YYYY",
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 year"
    }, {
      "period": "YTD",
      "label": "YTD"
    }, {
      "period": "MAX",
      "label": "MAX"
    } ]
  },

  "panelsSettings": {
    "usePrefixes": true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```

Here is how I'm trying to do:

```
//https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrdZgj
var chartData = [];
var chart;
generateChartData();

function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date( 2012, 0, 1 );
  firstDate.setDate( firstDate.getDate() - 500 );
  firstDate.setHours( 0, 0, 0, 0 );

  for ( var i = 0; i < 500; i++ ) {
    var newDate = new Date( firstDate );
    newDate.setDate( newDate.getDate() + i );

    var a = Math.round( Math.random() * ( 40 + i ) ) + 100 + i;
    var b = Math.round( Math.random() * 100000000 );

    chartData.push( {
      "date": newDate,
      "value": a,
      "volume": b
    } );
  }
}

chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataSets": [ {
    "color": "#b0de09",
    "fieldMappings": [ {
      "fromField": "value",
      "toField": "value"
    }, {
      "fromField": "volume",
      "toField": "volume"
    } ],
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "categoryField": "date"
  } ],


  "panels": [ {
    "title": "Value",
    "stockGraphs": [ {
      "id": "g1",
      "valueField": "value"
    } ],
    "stockLegend": {
      "valueTextRegular": " ",
      "markerType": "none"
    }
  } ],

  "chartScrollbarSettings": {
    "graph": "g1"
  },

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
    "graphBulletSize": 1,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.5
  },

  "periodSelector": {
    "periods": [ {
      "period": "DD",
      "count": 10,
      "label": "10 days"
    }, {
      "period": "MM",
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 month"
    }, {
      "period": "YYYY",
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 year"
    }, {
      "period": "YTD",
      "label": "YTD"
    }, {
      "period": "MAX",
      "label": "MAX"
    } ]
  },

  "panelsSettings": {
    "usePrefixes": true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
function insert_event(){
  chart.dataSets.stockEvents= [ {
      "date": new Date( 2010, 8, 19 ),
      "type": "sign",
      "backgroundColor": "#85CDE6",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "S",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2010, 10, 19 ),
      "type": "flag",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "backgroundAlpha": 0.5,
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "F",
      "description": "Some longer\ntext can also\n be added"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2010, 11, 10 ),
      "showOnAxis": true,
      "backgroundColor": "#85CDE6",
      "type": "pin",
      "text": "X",
      "graph": "g1",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2010, 11, 26 ),
      "showOnAxis": true,
      "backgroundColor": "#85CDE6",
      "type": "pin",
      "text": "Z",
      "graph": "g1",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 0, 3 ),
      "type": "sign",
      "backgroundColor": "#85CDE6",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "U",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 1, 6 ),
      "type": "sign",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "D",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 3, 5 ),
      "type": "sign",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "L",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 3, 5 ),
      "type": "sign",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "R",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 5, 15 ),
      "type": "arrowUp",
      "backgroundColor": "#00CC00",
      "graph": "g1",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 6, 25 ),
      "type": "arrowDown",
      "backgroundColor": "#CC0000",
      "graph": "g1",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    }, {
      "date": new Date( 2011, 8, 1 ),
      "type": "text",
      "graph": "g1",
      "text": "Longer text can\nalso be displayed",
      "description": "This is description of an event"
    } ]
  chart.validateNow();
}
insert_event()
```

The chart object is created, and then the function "insert_event()" is called with the events to be inserted.

Is there some way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the stockEvents array incorrectly. Note the difference between the two samples in how the stockEvents array is assigned to dataSets. In the first snippet, it's set right in the dataSets *array* at the first element, however, in your second snippet you're just treating dataSets as an *object*, not as an array. All you need to do is add the subscript to fix the assignment, i.e. `chart.dataSets[0].stockEvents = [/*your array */];`

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/1a284005d5212f073e0a7a1b19cd1380/?editors=0010)